# how to insert newline between two if conditions

Tags: coding-style, clang, clang-format

I am using clang-format to prettify some existing code. I want to insert a newline between two if conditions, like below code :

```
int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
  int x;                                                                        
  int   y;                                                                      

  if (x == 1)                                                                   
  {                                                                             
  }                                                                             
  if(y == 2)                                                                    
  {                                                                             
  }                                                                             
  return 0;                                                                     
}
```

should be changed to

```
int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
  int x;                                                                        
  int   y;                                                                      

  if (x == 1)                                                                   
  {                                                                             
  }
  /* inserted a newline */                                                                           
  if(y == 2)                                                                    
  {                                                                             
  }                                                                             
  return 0;                                                                     
}
```

Can this be done using clang-format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

**clang-format** just *format* code, it can not *modify* code. Your case is modifing AST of source code. Use RecursiveASTVisitor to find position
you want insert, then rewrite back to code.

Or you can just write a regex script, insert what you want. :)